# spring jdbcTemplate batch update return records inserted

Tags: java, spring

```
public void insertBatch(final List<Customer> customers){

     String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
        "(ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, ?, ?)";

      getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {


    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = customers.get(i);
        ps.setString(1, customer.getName());
        ps.setInt(2, customer.getAge() );
    }

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return customers.size();
    }
  });
}
```

Is there any way where I can get all the records inserted in this batch with primary key (ID) value as well in the above method itself. Or do I need to write a separate method to get the data.?
I am using oracle DB.

Comment: Just a quick info about the link provided in the comment above: it is entirely unrelated and doesn't even contain BatchPreparedStatementSetter at all. It also doesn't answer the question about retrieving the IDs of the created rows

Comment: There is pull request for this, check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/28132